# How do I make the OrbitControls in Three js honor changes to orientation of the OrthographicCamera?

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I use OrbitControls to allow the users to rotate and pan the screen. However I want to be able to set the rotation around the Z axis for the OrthographicCamera that the OrbitControls. I am able to change the position and the OrbitControls seem to honor that when I switch to a different view and back. However when I change the rotation around the Z axis for the OrthoGraphic camera, everytime I use the mouse to pan or rotate objects it jumps to 0 rotation and starts from there. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try `camera.up.set( - 1, 2, 0 ).normalize();`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Great! thanks. That seems to be exactly what I need. However I have difficulty understanding what really the up vector is. How do I give meaningful values to it so that I keep my Z pointed up but just change rotation around it? The Three js documentation just says "This is used by the lookAt method, for example, to determine the orientation of the result.
Default is Object3D.DefaultUp - that is, ( 0, 1, 0 )." Is there something more detailed you could point me to?

Comment: `OrbitControls` is not really designed to do what you appear to want. What is your use-case? Why do you want to tilt the camera left or right when using the control?

Comment: I think if I understand what the up vector is I could use this to address my use case. My use case is simple, lets say I am viewing the top of a building using the ortho camera. Now I want to set the initial orientation of the topview. i.e it should be rotated by 45 degree. Now I want to allow the user to have the ability to pan or rotate it. I understand what the camera position needs to be, I understand where the target needs to be. But in my mind I think they are in the same vertical, so how can I use the up vector to rotate either the object or the camera so the top view is tilted by 45deg

Comment: Orbit controls does not work properly if the camera is looking straight down or straight up. This is the reason for `spherical.makeSafe();` in the source code. I would not mess with the `up` vector. Instead, set the camera position like so: `camera.position.set( 0.0001 * Math.cos( theta ), desiredHeight, 0.0001 * Math.sin( theta ) );`